# How can I calculate the frequency of pixel change within a region of interest in an AVI file?

Tags: pixel, avi, frequency-analysis

I have a number of AVI files for which I can identify certain regions of interest.
I am interested in calculating the frequency of pixel change (e.g. from black to white, or some other change) within each region of interest. Is there any tool or workflow I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to do the following:

1. Extract each frame of the AVI into a bitmap (you could use something like FFmpeg)
2. Then read each pixel of the region into some type of array
3. Then compare each array to the first or previous depending on your needs to find differences, and then calculate the frequency of change.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) is a library that you can use with a lot of algorithms already developed for such tasks. It works with python and also C++ among other lenguages.